# Transform existing C++ OpenGL project from glut/glew to GLFW

Tags: opengl, c++, glut, glfw, glew

Is it possible to easly transform existing glut/glew to GLFW API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very easy. GLFW even uses callbacks for things like mouse/keyboard/controller input events, similar to glut, so the program can follow the same basic structure more or less. I use GLEW with GLFW, so no difference there.